# chrome.hid.send fails on second use

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, hid

Something about my use of `chrome.hid.send` seems to be leaving the bus in a bad state.  I consistently can NOT get my second usage of the API call to work.  Sometimes, it will also fail on the first usage.  WITH THE EXACT SAME CODE, I can come back and try a while later (maybe 10min) and the first send will work.

The device I'm working with does not return a response to all messages sent to it.  The test message for example, is just a dummy message that is ignored by the device.  I've tested this both on a mac and a PC.  My call stack depth is 2 at this point in my application (literally first one is kicked off by a button click and then a `setTimeout` calls the same method 5s later).

I've testing sending buffers of length 64Bytes as well as 58Bytes.  The properties from the HidDeviceInfo object read "maxInputReportSize":64,"maxOutputReportSize":64

Params on first usage:

[image]

Params on second usage:

[image]

I really can't identify how I'm using the API incorrectly.  When messages do succeed, I can see them on the device side.

```
// Transmits the given data
//
// @param[in] outData,       The data to send as an ArrayBuffer
// @param[in] onTxCompleted, The method called on completion of the outgoing transfer.  The return
//                           code is passed as a string.
// @param[in] onRxCompleted, The method called on completion of the incoming transfer.  The return
//                           code is passed as a string along with the response as an ArrayBuffer.
send: function(outData, onTxCompleted, onRxCompleted) {
  if (-1 === connection_) {
    console.log("Attempted to send data with no device connected.");
    return;
  }

  if (0 == outData.byteLength) {
    console.log("Attempted to send nothing.");
    return;
  }

  if (COMMS.receiving) {
    console.log("Waiting for a response to a previous message.  Aborting.");
    return;
  }

  if (COMMS.transmitting) {
    console.log("Waiting for a previous message to finish sending.  Aborting.");
    return;
  }

  COMMS.transmitting = true;
  var dummyUint8Array = new Uint8Array(outData);
  chrome.hid.send(connection_, REPORT_ID, outData, function() {
    COMMS.transmitting = false;

    if (onTxCompleted) {
      onTxCompleted(chrome.runtime.lastError ? chrome.runtime.lastError.message : '');
    }

    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.log('Error in COMMS.send: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }

    // Register a response handler if one is expected
    if (onRxCompleted) {
      COMMS.receiving = true;
      chrome.hid.receive(connection_, function(reportId, inData) {
        COMMS.receiving = false;
        onRxCompleted(chrome.runtime.lastError ? chrome.runtime.lastError.message : '', inData);
      });
    }
  });
}


// Example usage
var testMessage = new Uint8Array(58);
var testTransmission = function() {
  message[0] = 123;
  COMMS.send(message.buffer, null, null);
  setTimeout(testTransmission, 5000);
};
testTranmission();
```

Comment: A couple questions. What version of Chrome are you running? What is the result of the second usage? Is the callback never executed? Is chrome.runtime.lastError set to an error?

Comment: Version 41.0.2240.0 canary (64-bit).  When it fails and I specify a method for onTxCompleted, my passed callback is executed just fine.

Comment: I get problems in the latest stable (regular) chrome as well though.

Comment: So the failure is that no data is sent to the device or is chrome.runtime.lastError.message set to "Transfer failed." in the callback?

Comment: chrome.runtime.lastError is set to 'Transfer failed' and no data is sent to the device.  Always happens on Windows 7 machines (tested three) and most-the-time happens on macs.  I consistently got it to happen on mac every second send.  Now it happens on mac almost every time, too.

Comment: Add "--enable-logging --v=1" to your Chrome command line arguments (see full logging instructions here: http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and then looks for lines containing "hid_connection" in chrome_debug.log. These will give you the low-level operating system errors.

Comment: I send a single message that failed and found: ...`hid_connection_win.cc(86)] HID transfer failed: The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation.`  When I inspect the ArrayBuffer passed to `chrome.hid.send`, it has one byte as expected (0x16).  Is that invalid for some reason?

Comment: Try sending a full 64-byte ArrayBuffer instead of 58 bytes. I recall Windows being picky about buffer sizes.

Comment: That's fixing it on Windows so far!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Windows requires buffers to be the full report size expected by the device. I  have filed [a bug](https://crbug.com/439775) against Chromium to track adding a workaround or at least a better error message to pinpoint the problem.

In general you can get more detailed error messages from the chrome.hid API by enabling verbose logging with the `--enable-logging --v=1` command line options. Full documentation of Chrome logging is [here](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging).